# Compiling using Ivy results in ERROR in Cannot combine @Input decorators with query decorators

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-ivy

I am trying out the new Ivy feature in Angular 8 but when compiling the solution I get the error:

> ERROR in Cannot combine @Input decorators with query decorators

I am using the `@ViewChild` and `@ViewChildren` in two places. I commented them out but I am still getting this error. I am using the `@Input` parameter in a few places and some of them are directly bound in the view.

Could that be causing the error?

Any other ideas?

Comment: Any fix for the above? I am facing the same issue. I am not using @input and Query decorator together. And it is quite hard to find inside the third parties library.

Comment: Hi @RohitDubey I decided to wait for the final release and see if the there will be better error handling rather spending to much time on this.

Comment: Try this solution. It helped me...
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65566589/2315972

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your 3rd party libraries - sadly right now hard to find this issue as the compiler has no additional info.

Comment: Any update on this answer, how to identify the defect, because im facing this too.

Comment: Sadly, I had to remove each 3rd party one by one. Only hint i can give is to start with older libraries that may not have had an update since Ivy introduction. Newer libraries / update support Ivy. Huge pain i know.