# Every project's component 'should create' test fails with error 'Cannot combine @Input decorators with query decorators'

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have a pretty large project with tons of components in it.

Trying to write some tests and encounter a problem immediately.

[image: every test fails with such error]

What i have tried to do:

- update to a new Angular version. Didn't help.
- run test after removing every ng-library from project. Didn't help.
- find any usage of @Input with query decorators in project. There is no such things.

I believe that it is a very specific problem, but maybe someone can at least suggest a direction to dig

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot combine @Input decorators with query decorators using Ivy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56457566/cannot-combine-input-decorators-with-query-decorators-using-ivy)

Answer (score 0):

In my case problem was in these lines of code in the other component

```
@ContentChild(TemplateRef)
 @Input() someRef: TemplateRef<any>;
```